# Gm_download() not work properly with name

Tags: javascript, firefox, tampermonkey, userscripts

Using tampermonkey on firefox. I have script that get url's then with `for (var line in url)`
execute `Gm_download(line, name)`.

`var name= count + id`
Problem is that id variable sometime contain " / " and " : ". First one make directory instead one line name, second one (I don't know does problem from that) is broke Gm_download. How I can make Gm_download to ignore that characters or accept it like name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These characters have special meaning in a file system so you can't use them in file names.

You can replace all of them with their full-width forms so `/` becomes `／` :

```
name = name.replace(/[*/:<>?\\|]/g, s =>
  String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + 0xFF00 - 0x20));
```